# My iOS app is freezing on the launch screen after upgrading to Xamarin Forms 5.0 (Visual Studio 2019 Mac)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to fix a problem, that started after upgrading to Xamarin Forms 5.0.
I was using the Xamarin.Forms.4.8.0.1560. Everything was working fine.
Now, the app freezes in the launch screen, on my iPhone.
I can't find any hint on the console.

Has anyone facing the same issue? Or is there any tips?

PS: I only use this project for my iOS version.

Thank you.

Here is the Console Output:

```
    Launched application 'br.com.movisis.demonstracao' on 'iPhone Rafael' with pid 6672
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/WebP.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.InputKit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/XFormsTouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Ricardo.MWPhotoBrowser.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Lottie.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Lottie.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.Media.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/SignaturePad.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/SignaturePad.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/HtmlLabel.Forms.Plugin.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Licensing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Core.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Core.XForms.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Microsoft.CSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.DataSource.Portable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.GridCommon.Portable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRating.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRangeSlider.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRangeSlider.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfRangeSlider.XForms.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.DownloadManager.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.DownloadManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.ImageEdit.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Transformations.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.Data.Portable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfComboBox.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/Plugin.ImageEdit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/MoviAuto.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.IO.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/OpenTK-1.0.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Aplicacao.cs:1510,1' to bool Componentes.Aplicacao.OperacaoPecaServico (string operacao, string tipo, int empresa, int revenda, long contato, int nroSolicitacao, int nroLancamento, int codigo, double valorUnitario, double quantidade, string tipoServico, string desSolicitacao, double pctDesconto, double valDesconto, bool desconto, double valDescontoPecas, double valDescontoServicos, double pctDescontoPecas, double pctDescontoServicos) [0x0012d].
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Thread started:  #8
Thread started:  #9
Thread started:  #10
Thread started:  #11
Thread started:  #12
Thread started:  #13
Thread finished:  #12
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
Thread finished:  #10
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Utils.cs:179,1' to long Componentes.MyExtensions.AsLong (System.Data.DataRow row, string ColumnName) [0x00019].
Thread finished:  #9
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E43E5CEA-823B-43E7-A875-F5AF636D434E/MoviAuto.iOS.app/System.Text.Encoding.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
Thread finished:  #11
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
```

Comment: Post logs from console, this question needs more details

Comment: Could you post the code of the MainPage ? By the way, did you test it on Android ?

Comment: @DimaRostopira.. I've updated with the log from console.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't use it for android. don't have a working project to test it in android. I'll try to clean the main page, to see if there is any change.